# julia subtype logic does not make any sense to me

Tags: julia, subtype, mapping

I am using map on a subtype but it does not seems to work and I always get the error message. is anything wrong with my code or just I used the map function incorrectly .and I cant get really the Type, Subtype and the constructor logic in Julia. Thanx in advance

```
abstract type AbstractModel end


function validator(::Type{T}) where {T<:AbstractModel}
     #fieldtype(T,1)<:Type ||error("Validation error for type of default"," in the Type $T accure the error") 
     fieldtype(T,3)<:String ||error("Validation error for type of default"," in the Type $T accure the error"  )
     fieldtype(T,4)<:Int||error("Validation error for type of default"," in the Type $T accure the error"  ) 
     fieldtype(T,5)<:Int ||error("Validation error for type of default"," in the Type $T accure the error"  ) 
end

struct Field5 <:AbstractModel
    type
    default
    description
    min
    max
    Field5(type,default,description,min,max)=new("","","this is descriptio",7,10)
end

map(validator, subtypes(AbstractModel))
```

Comment: You have not added any type annotations to your struct definition `Field5`. So every field has the type `Any`. It doesn't help that you are creating an _instance_ of `Field5` that you give some values since it is only the _type_ you send to `AbstractModel`, not the _instance_. Also, it is very strange that the function `AbstractModel` has the name of a type, but is not a constructor. Abstract type constructors should anyway not exist, so you should rename this function.

Comment: Thanks for updating the function name. Now try this: `fieldtype(Field5, 3)`. It will return `Any`, as expected.

Comment: thanx for your comment :) I got your point but I do not think it will work for my approche, cause I cant give the attributes in Field5 a specific type, rather I need it to be any but when it instantiated if the instance have a wrong value it should throw me an erorr

Comment: Then this will never work, and you must run your validator on a type _instance_, not on the type itself. But you should almost never use structs with `Any` fields, because they have _terrible_ performance. For example, you can use a parametric type definition.

Comment: thank you I will try it :) the Subtype and Type logic in Julia is totally new for me

Comment: This isn't any different from other languages, or even OOP languages like Python. If you ask for the types of attributes on a Python Class, it won't help if you create an object of that class with specific attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of looks like you just want to give fields types that you don't know in advance and restrict those types, you can do that with parameters:

```
struct Field5{A<:Type,
              B<:Any,
              C<:String, 
              D<:Int,
              E<:Int}
    type::A
    default::B
    description::C
    min::D
    max::E
end

x1 = Field5(Float64,"b","c",7,10) # works
x2 = Field5(Float64,"b","c",7,1.0) # MethodError because 1.0 is not <: Int
```

Alternatively, if you didn't want to restrict the types but only check it with `validator`, then you do this:

```
struct Field5{A,B,C,D,E}
    type::A
    default::B
    description::C
    min::D
    max::E
end

function validator(::Type{T}) where {T<:Field5}
     fieldtype(T,1)<:Type ||error("Validation error for type of default"," in the Type $T accure the error") 
     fieldtype(T,3)<:String ||error("Validation error for type of default"," in the Type $T accure the error"  )
     fieldtype(T,4)<:Int||error("Validation error for type of default"," in the Type $T accure the error"  ) 
     fieldtype(T,5)<:Int ||error("Validation error for type of default"," in the Type $T accure the error"  ) 
end

x1 = Field5(Float64,"b","c",7,10) # works
x2 = Field5(Float64,"b","c",7,1.0) # works

# note that x1 and x2 have different concrete types; Field5 is abstract
# now validator can tell if a concrete type fits its criteria

validator(typeof(x1)) # true
validator(typeof(x2)) # Validation error because 1.0 is not <:Int
```